# How can i List Another site's RSS feed on my own site hompage

Tags: plugins, rss, feed, aggregator

**My question is:**
How can I list another website's RSS feed on my own site' homepage, such, that when a visitor clicks on any of those lists, it directs the visitor to the website i fetched those RSS feeds from?

**FYI:** I am using Wordpress.